# Excel - test 3 cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to perform a that tests one cell, then if false investigates two other cells.

E.g. 
If `cell 1` says *yes* then result = **yes**, if `cell 1` says *no* then test `cell 2` and `cell 3`; if they say *yes* then result = **yes**.

e.g. something like:

```
=IF(OR(H2="100%", I2="investigate" AND j2="100%"),"100%")
```

obviously that isn't working but hopefully someone understands my ramble.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of data you are putting into your fields, I have used the following:

```
=IF(B3="yes","yes",IF(C3="yes",D3,"no"))
```

[image]

How it works is, it checks what is in the first cell, if this is true, puts a "yes", if this is false, it checks cell 2, now if cell 2 is true it puts in whatever is in cell 3 so if cell 3 is a yes, it prints yes if cell 3 is a no, it prints no.

Technically my formula doesn't compare if cell 2 & 3 are both true.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF(H2="100%", "YES", IF(AND(I2="Investigate", J2="100%"), "YES", "NO"))
```

This tests `H2`, if the value is `100%` then it will show `YES` if the value is anything else then it will test to see if the value of `I2` is `Investigate` and the value of `J2` is `100%`. If so it will give you `YES` if not it will give you `NO`.

Note that the value `100%` is a string, if you calculate the percentage then you will need to remove the speech marks and change the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` is not an operator in Excel, but a function, like `OR`:

`=IF(OR(H2="100%",AND(I2="investigate",j2="100%")),"100%")`