# Excel, too many arguments for this function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to create a sheet that can convert shift times into hours worked but will also recognise text values. Been playing around with the IF function and can get it to do one or the other but not both together. The two formulas I have are

```
=IF('Shift Times'!C6<=0,"",(TEXT(RIGHT('Shift Times'!C6,4),"00\:00")-TEXT(LEFT('Shift Times'!C6,4),"00\:00"))*24-0.5)
AND
IF('Shift Times'!C6="Sick","Sick"))
```

Is there a way of combining these two formulas so that they work together? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - test 3 cells](https://superuser.com/questions/1212345/excel-test-3-cells)

Comment: `if(condition){ do firstthing; }else{ if(othercondition){do secondthing; }else{ do thirdthing; } }`. You can use the same logic on Excel functions.

Comment: What are the shift times? Is it a single value? I assume it has to be a range. If so, what format is the range? In your code, you're only looking at `C6` suggesting there is only a single value. How is this shift timeS

Comment: for excel 2016 users (not backward compatible) consider using IFS or SWITCH

Comment: The format of the shift times is: 1000-1730 (for example) so I input that into a worksheet called "shift times" and then have another sheet called "hours worked" which converts the shift time into actual hours worked using the above formula. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AND` and `OR` functions to evaluate multiple possibilities at once.

Use `AND` in cases where ALL conditions have be true. For example, if you want to enter "Sick" in situations where time is 0 and status is sick, where time is in column `C` and status is in column `D`, you could use:

```
=IF(AND(C6=0,D6="Sick"),"Sick",<calculation>)
```

Use `OR` in cases where any one condition has to be true. For example, if column C might have 0 hours or it may have the word "sick" in it, you could use:

```
=IF(OR(C6<=0,C6="Sick"),"Sick",<calculation>)
```

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me get most of the way there. Is there a limit on calculations you make in one formula?

Comment: @Stuck You can nest up to seven `IF` formulae together. If you need more than that, you may need to use a different solution, like a lookup table.